# How to get current column and its sorting direction of QTableView

Tags: python, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

[image]

This code creates a single `QTableView`. Clicking the column displays the arrow that indicates the direction of column sorting. Clicking the tableView's item itself prints out the clicked index. When the tableView item is clicked I want to know what of three columns (headers) is current (the column with the arrow displayed) and what direction the sorting arrow is pointing: up or down. How to achieve this?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.items = [[1, 'one', 'ONE'], [2, 'two', 'TWO'], [3, 'three', 'THREE']]

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3 
    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return 

        if role in [QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole]:
            return self.items[index.row()][index.column()]

def onClick(index):
    print 'clicked index:  %s'%index

def sortIndicatorChanged(column=None, sortOrder=None):
    print 'sortIndicatorChanged: column: %s, sortOrder: %s'%(column, sortOrder)

tableModel=Model()
tableView=QtGui.QTableView() 
tableView.setModel(tableModel)
tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)
tableView.clicked.connect(onClick)
tableView.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorChanged.connect(sortIndicatorChanged)
tableView.show()

app.exec_()
```